# Deletar imagem do Diretório - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho no meu método destroy o seguinte código:

```
try{  
    Tecnico::find($id_tecnico)->delete();  
    DB::commit();
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', true);
}catch (\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback();
    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
}
```

Como eu faço para deletar também uma imagem que está vinculada ao técnico que está sendo deletado?

As imagens ficam na pasta public, e o caminho/nome fica em um campo "assinatura" da tabela.

Acho que eu teria que pegar esse caminho e usar algum método para deletar o arquivo, mas ai não sei como fazer esse "delete".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Deletar um arquivo

File::delete($filename);

// Deletar vários arquivos

File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);

// Deletar um array de arquivos

$files = array($file1, $file2);

File::delete($files);
```

Fonte: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133/deleting-a-file

Comment: show, obrigado!